# Why I got this exception :Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, jscript

Why I got this error

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
```

this error appears when the event for Save command is started

```
  Protected Sub DataList1_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListCommandEventArgs) Handles dlMainTraing.ItemCommand
        If e.CommandName = "Save" Then
            Dim lblMainId = CType(dlMainTraing.Items(e.Item.ItemIndex).FindControl("Train_M_IndxLabel"), Label)
            Dim txtSubTrainingName2 = CType(dlMainTraing.Items(e.Item.ItemIndex).FindControl("txtSubTrainingName"), TextBox)
            Dim a = addSubTraining(CInt(lblMainId.Text), txtSubTrainingName2.Text)
            ' Dim gvSubTraning As GridView = CType(e.Item.FindControl("gvSubTraning"), GridView)
            'gvSubTraning.DataBind()
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the top of your .aspx page, set EnableEventValidation to false.

[image]

Comment: This just hides the error. The effects of this error is not resolved by setting these properties.

Comment: Thank you ... Its pain to use aspx pages